# FullCalendar highlight row

Tags: jquery, css, fullcalendar

I'd like to highlight an arbitrary set of rows within [FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar) using the AgendaWeek view. Since each row has it's own css class (for instance, fc-slot32), I figured this wouldn't be much of a problem. However, when I apply a background colour to this row, it messes with the calendar grid. More specifically, it removes the separating borders between days on that row.

I'm unsure as to how FullCalendar actually achieves the calendar grid in the first place - does anyone know how I can possibly highlight the row without removing the grid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know what row you want highlighted, this would work:

```
$('.fc-slot5').css({'background-color':'yellow', 'opacity':0.5 });
```