# fullcalendar Make more emphasis in BusinessHours

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

It is possible to emphasize business hours in `fullcalendar` by changing the background of these cells so as to make them more visible?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to set via js of fullcalendar, just via css.
there are two examples:

[Is it possible to do alternating row background colours in FullCalendar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6330924/is-it-possible-to-do-alternating-row-background-colours-in-fullcalendar)

[FullCalendar highlight row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14537796/fullcalendar-highlight-row)

cheers

**Edit**

There is a solution; [Background Events](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/Background_Events/) an example:

[How to grey out non working day in agendaDay view with arshaw fullcalendar v2.3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30475236/how-to-grey-out-non-working-day-in-agendaday-view-with-arshaw-fullcalendar-v2-3)

Comment: Thanks @LakiGeri. I have just found it! For example I've changed nonbusiness background like this:  .fc-nonbusiness{background:#777777}

Comment: It is a better solution (defining `Background Events`) I guess.

Comment: It is an interesting solution, but I like businessHours because I can deny dropping over there:   eventConstraint: "businessHours",